# Using fluent NHibernate to map a read only sql view

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to get Fluent Nhibernate to Automap read-only views that do not have a primary or composite key specified.  It seems like it is possible as the API document for ClassMap exposes a default constructor for Id().

http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/ClassMap%601.htm

it says

*IdentityPart Id()
Create an Id that doesn't have a corresponding property in the domain object, or a column in the database. This is mainly for use with read-only access and/or views. Defaults to an int identity with an "increment" generator.*

I have tried to override the mapping for the entity which corresponds to my view, and have removed the primary key convention that specifies the Id field name.  It adds an `id` column to queries on the view which fail because there is no such column.

I am trying to get rid of fake primary keys on my views as I think there should be a better way to do this.

Here is the override snippet I am using

```
public class PersonMap: IAutoMappingOverride<Person>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Person> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

The way around this is to typically assign an arbitrary property to be the id and its generated by assigned. This is essentially the same as doing Map.

```
public class ItemViewMap : IAutoMappingOverride<ItemView>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<ItemView> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.Column).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isnt that exactly what the OP didnt want to do??

Comment: No, he only stipulated that he didnt want to have a fake, useless, primary key. I am suggesting that he use a column that actually has value to him, and just map it as ID rather than as a regular property. It shouldn't make any difference to nhibernate and should get him around the problem.

Comment: Since these are sql views, uniqueness sometimes must be determined by a number of properties.  To accomplish this, you must establish a composite key, and override the Equals and GetHashCode methods for the entity.  My hope was that I could get around establishing any id as it is a read only construct anyways.